# Disable GetCapabilities in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, wms, getcapabilities

My project currently uses `GeoServer 2.6.2` to serve out a few WFS and WMS layers to our application.

The results of some penetration testing raised the fact that GeoServer can be called with GetCapabilities which will then give out some juicy information that could be used against us.

Is there a way, specifically from within GeoServer, that you can disable the GetCapabilities requests or block them?

There is currently no need for the operation as we only use it ourselves.

Comment: Use security http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/security/webadmin/services.html or GeoFence http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/community/geofence-server/index.html. But I wonder what secret information GetCapabilities can reveal, I think that it is just advertising which layers are available in the service.

Comment: What information you rely to that `GetCapabilities` reveals? Usually the actual data is much more security relevant. Are you scared someone could write you an email? Don´t provide your mail-adress.

Comment: The concern from the pen testing was about host names and other server information from getCapabilities and other functions

Comment: @user30184 thanks for your comment, that is what I was looking for.

Comment: Why don't you just set up a proxy, to hide the host names

Comment: if you are the only users then block your firewall to the GeoServer host so no one out side can see it. If people outside use the GeoServer then they must be able to see the machine and the getCapabilities request is essential for thier clients

Comment: The service is used by client js in a public facing website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To kill this thread what I did was follow the security docs that user30184 commented: [How to disable getCapabilities in GeoSserver](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/181258/how-to-disable-getcapabilities-in-geoserver#comment273097_181258) http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/security/webadmin/services.html

So within geoserver web interface > Services I added some rules to restrict some of the Services' functions.

So that when they are hit you get an authentication error.

I am aware that this is not necessarily to everyone's taste, but it is all that I needed for my situation.

None the less I think that the answers and comments on this thread will serve to help others down the line. Thank you too all contributors.

Answer (score 8):

The reason why GeoServer (as every server compliant to the [OpenGIS Webservice](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Geospatial_Consortium)-format) provides this function is to be able to determine what your WMS or WFS is able to do, which kind of data they use (spatial reference, accuracy, layers), what the extent for them (bounding box) is and who might be responsible for issues when having problems on dealing with the service (service-admin).

I strongly would not recommend do deactivate this, as it is needed for every kind of automatic search for your service. The function simply provides metadata about your services, I doubt there are security-issues which it hands out.

Even noticing that you´re using the service only yourself does not justify disabling this as there might be collegues that do not understand every single parameter or every method that is provided by your WFS for exapmle. Looking into the document simplifies the process on getting all those information.

However if you really have to do this you may simply deactivate the servlet which is related to the function. As GeoServer is a simple servlet-container it provides a `web.xml`-file which you may modify. Simply delete the mservlet-mapping for `GetCapabilities` and you´re done. See this [doc from oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/webapp/configureservlet.html) for how to do this.

Anyway I doubt you can do much without the function, as many products (ArcGIS, OpenLayers, ...) use this information before even making any request for your actual data.

Comment: Since when does OpenLayers, do a GetCapabilities Request?

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe Not? Thought so from my memories. However long time ago, thanks for the hint.

Comment: We use ol3 in the application, and simply call the wms and wfs layers directly, so have no need for getCapabilities.  Regarding your answer it is right, and was one way of solving the issue.  But I was looking from within geoserver, and @user30184 comment is what I've used.

Comment: I think the solution provided by @user30184 internally uses this technic, however glad to help you.

Comment: But if I use something like fiddler I'll be able to see the actual requests being sent to all those hosts, so you won't have gained anything.

Comment: We proxy the wfs/wms requests through our app

Comment: Then why not simply deactivate the access to geoserver from outside the proxy at all? Meaning access to the server should not be permited whithout pusing the proxy.

Comment: We do, but the proxy is part of the app, so if you hit www.myapp.com/gis/wfs?getfeatures or whatever it proxies it to our geoserver install. Perhaps it is a different style of proxying than yours though. Don't worry about it now, I've got a solution from user30184, I'll add it as an answer later. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you only use the service yourself then the solution would be to only serve fake metainformation.

What I think could be used against you is the contacts information and other metadata. Simply fake this, and your pentesters should be happy. That way you retain getCapabilities functionality, while not providing any identifying data to potential attackers.

You could also reveal a bit more on what exactly the pentest identified as possible attack vectors. Then we could better discuss mitigation stratgies.